# IntelliJ Debugger slow: Method breakpoints may dramatically slow down debugging

Tags: intellij-idea

When I start IntelliJ debugger, it shows a tooltip that says:

> Method breakpoints may dramatically slow down debugging

[image: Screenshot: tooltip: Method breakpoints may dramatically slow down debugging]

The debugger takes a long time to start. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 288, accepted):

Turn off the method breakpoints. You can see all your breakpoints through Run | View Breakpoints (Ctrl - Shift -F8 )

[image]

Comment: But surely removing your breakpoints defeats the purpose of debugging? Or I'm missing something.

Comment: @arush436 The number of situations where you need a  "method breakpoint" (!= regular breakpoint) are very limited.

Comment: And what is the difference then between a method breakpoint and a regular breakpoint?

Comment: @jrahhali See [Method breakpoint](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/types-of-breakpoints.html#method_breakpoint) and [Line breakpoint](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/types-of-breakpoints.html#d1012784e109)

Comment: Here's an updated link to the different [types of breakpoints](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/using-breakpoints.html#breakpoint-types).

Comment: For most scenarios, you definitely DO NOT want this enabled.  It has its uses, of course, but was likely enabled unintentionally by the developer when clicking through their debug tools.

Comment: Thanks, works in Android Studio Chipmonk | 2021.2.1 Patch 2

Answer (score 35):

[image]

Turn off the method breakpoint from the debug panel.
Here is a screenshot.

Answer (score 15):

In IDEA 2017.1 Emulated Method Breakpoints were introduced: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/using-breakpoints.html#method_breakpoint
They allow using method breakpoints without the performance penalty.
Enabled by default.

Comment: If you see this message you may have (like me) clicked "Cancel emulation" on a popup. To re-enable it go to the break point in show-breakpoints and check "Emulated".

Answer (score 10):

From the JetBrains Team: "Method breakpoints will slow down debugger a lot because of the JVM design, they are expensive to evaluate. Remove method breakpoints and consider using the regular line breakpoints.". See [more](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544799-Java-slow-performance-or-hangups-when-starting-debugger-and-stepping).

To make the long story short, it seems that the root issue is that Method Breakpoints are implemented by using **JPDA**'s **Method Entry** & **Method Exit** feature. This implementation requires the JVM to fire an event each time **any** thread enters **any** method and when **any** thread exits **any** method.

Answer (score 7):

Look for the red diamond icons (not red circles) in your code, those represent the method breakpoints. Most probably you set them at get()/set() methods in Kotlin.

Comment: Unfortunately this warning goes off with breakpoints set in `onClick` methods, which are *very useful* places to put a breakpoint.  And they won't cause a slow-down at all.  Sigh.

Answer (score 7):

In my case, I used Android Studio, When I set Break-Point on a `method name line` (called `Java Method Break-Point`), The Android Studio show me the this warning and debugging was so slow...

By `removing this Break-Point` my problem solved...

[image]

[image]

Comment: thank you this solved my issue. I had accidentally added method breakpoint in a interface class.. I just wasted 8 hrs scratching my head, installing new version of IntelliJ. Your post helped me :-)

Answer (score 3):

Practical advice that I follow:

1. mute all the breakpoints while the app is coming up.
2. enable breakpoints only while debugging that flow.

Of course, it won't help if you are trying to debug something which happens during app startup.

Answer (score -2):

View Breakpoints - (Ctrl - Shift -F8 )
Remove all method Breakpoints.
rerun the application in debugging mode .
its working f