# Android Studio 2.2.1: Slow Debugging

Tags: android, debugging, android-studio

Since the update to version 2.21 the `Debugging` has become very slow. One exmaple: When I start my app without the debugger in completes one function in less than 2 seconds. With the debugger connected I have to wait more than 4 minutes for its completion. The update `2.2.2` did not solve this problem. What can I do to increase the debug speed again?

Comment: what is your function doing? without any example(and crystal magic ball) it's hard to talk about possible reasons

Comment: @ilmash: It does not depend on the function - this behaviour is the same for all functions I have tested; even when they only perform simple operations.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Make sure your debugger option is correct.

[image]

Comment: How would someone display the "debugger option" you are talking about? I don't see anything like the image.

Comment: that image has no context, how do you get there?

Comment: Here where you can find it : After you run the debug button, next(2-3 button after) to that "Attach debugger to android process" button would be there, just click and choose your package and choose the "Java only" from the select box.

Comment: so when im using kotlin so what should i do #ZhenXu

Answer (score 9):

See this, it helped me massively:

[Intellij Debugger slow: Method breakpoints my dramatically slow down debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27966065/intellij-debugger-slow-method-breakpoints-my-dramatically-slow-down-debugging)

I was waiting up to a minute when debugging for the first webservice call to return. CPU and memory monitors peaked during this period. Removed the Java Method Breakpoints and hey presto, back to normal.

Comment: Had slow and difficult to use debugging with a clean Android Studio 3.0 (canary build at this time). This includes debugging without method breakpoints. Fix was to return to 2.3.2 at this time. Same code. YMMV.

Answer (score 2):

check your break-points added to your code for debugging before, I fixed this problem with release break-points that added on UI function

Comment: a small answer like this can be comment

Answer (score 1):

Changing Debugger option to Java Only in Android Studio Flamingo (same option for Kotlin):

[image: Go to Run -> Edit Configurations]

[image: choose tab Debugger in app]

Answer (score 0):

Check as well if you didn't add function breakpoints. They are drastically slowing down the debugger.

You can check the line breakpoints in Debug menu -> View Breakpoints icon (Ctrl + Shift + F8)
The function line breakpoints are in red rhombus shape (not circle). Either disable them or better remove them.
You should observe immediate improvement in debugger speed.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Breakpoints image]

Unchecked these check boxes. It solved my issue