# Stuck at whitescreen when starting app with debugger - Android Studio 4.1.2

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-4.1

when I start my android application on a physical device with 'Debug App' runs into a whitescreen and does not proceed.

If I do the same without debugger and attaching it afterwards it works fine.

What I tried:

- disable "allow paralell run"
- clean application and delete .gradle folder
- restart adb
- restart device
- restart android studio

Another thread suggests to disable instant run but I did not found that on Android Studio 4.1.2.

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Can you try `adb shell am clear-debug-app`?

Comment: i tried but did not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried everything you guys suggested, but only a clean reinstall worked

Answer (score 1):

please try this :

- disable Verify apps over USB on your android physical device developer option
- Ensure select debug app is not pointing to any app on the device
- ensure USB Debugging (Security settings) is turned off
- Disable any antivirus app you may have on the android physical device
- Perform file --> Invalidate Caches on your android studio
- Do a rebuild

then try debugging again..

Answer (score 1):

I had a different issue, by default (at least in my Android Studio) I had method breakpoints turned on. This was causing my old Android device to stutter and just show blank screen.
Everything started working much smoother after I removed them.
You can find how to do it here : [IntelliJ Debugger slow: Method breakpoints may dramatically slow down debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27966065/intellij-debugger-slow-method-breakpoints-may-dramatically-slow-down-debugging)