Why is Android Studio processing classes for emulated method each time when trying to attach a debugger?
I use - Android Studio Jellyfish | 2023.3.1 Patch 1
The problem is that each time when I try to attach the debugger AS starts to process classes for the emulated method

What is a possible issue? Because previously it didn't work like that

Have you set any breakpoints? That method breakpoints can take some time is nothing new https://stackoverflow.com/q/27966065/150978 therefore my guess is that there are still some breakpoints set that cause this behavior.
